# Управление фрагментами

Tags: android, android-fragment

Всем привет!

Делаю приложение с использованием 5 фрагментов.
В приложении будет 5 кнопок внизу и выше будет framlayout.
В контейнер будут загружаться фрагменты в зависимости от нажатой кнопки.

Как я сейчас делаю:
в onClick определенной кнопки:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.appFragmentContainer, myFragment).commit();
```

и в целом все ок, фрагменты меняются.

НО

меня терзают сомнения, что я делаю это правильно.
Пытался найти статьи о механизме работы с фрагментами - везде одно и тоже, но как правильно управлять фрагментами не нашел.

Буду признателен за помощь и советы!

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Так вполне правильно , что конкретно вас смущает ?

Comment: Хм.. может стоило бы объявить один фрагмент менеджер, фрагмент транзакцию и делать через них, а не в одну строчку так ?

Comment: 5 кнопок внизу это обычные табы?

Comment: Ага. Активити выглядит так: рут элемент relative, внизу linerlayout с 5 кнопками, а все остальное framelayout - туда будут загружаться фрагменты.

Comment: Можете сделать метод , вызывающий фрагмент и передавать туда только id фрагмента , который должен быть показан . Будет меньше повторяющегося кода . В рефакторинге AS даже есть такая приблуда , чтобы сделать это практически автоматически

Comment: Спасибо! А что такое "рефакторинге AS" ?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что имеется в виду меню Refactor в Android Studio.

Comment: Хм.. в меню Refactor есть что-то вроде Find and Replace Code Duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобный подход вполне корректен. Единственное, что теряется в таком случае по сравнению с активностями - это управление стеком переходов назад. Если он нужен, то следует к каждой транзакции добавлять `.addToBackStack(null)` и также переопределить метод `onBackPressed()` в активности, чтобы он возвращал назад через `FragmentManager.popBackStack()`, когда `FragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()` сообщает о том, что есть фрагменты в стеке. В остальном никаких проблем быть не должно.

Comment: Спасибо) Правда, мне не нужно, чтобы нажатие на кнопку назад показывало предыдущий фрагмент. Сейчас нажатие на кнопку назад просто выходит из приложения.

Comment: @Andrew ну, тебе так и нужно?

Comment: В ТЗ ничего об этом не сказано, так что так устроит:) спасибо;)

Answer (score 1):

Если есть несколько фрагментов вызываемые из одного активити то можно оптимизировать код по двум направлениям :
1. один FragmentManager , чтобы не плодить объекты ,не нужные в данном случае
2.Вызов перенести в метод , чтобы не писать много раз одно и то же ( и для общей эстетичности кода)

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity {

 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
 Fragment1 fragment1;
 Fragment2 fragment2;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
     fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     fragment1 = new Fragment1();
     fragment2 = new Fragment2();

     replaceFragment(fragment1); // показать первый фрагмент

     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putDouble("data", data);
     fragment2.setArguments(args); 
     replaceFragment(fragment2); //показать второй фрагмент
    ...

 void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
  }
```

}

Comment: О, так читабельнее код и меньше) Но мне в один из фрагментов(фрагмент с гугл-картой) надо передать параметры координаты. Передаю так `fTrans = fManager.beginTransaction();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putDouble("lat", mLatitude);
        args.putDouble("lat", mLongitude);
        fragMap.setArguments(args);
        fTrans.replace(R.id.appFragmentContainer, fragMap);
        fTrans.commit();`

Comment: ну если несколько таких фрагментов с аргументами , то можно перегрузить метод `replaceFragment(Fragment fragment , Bundle args)`  . Если он один , то можно и так вызвать , прикрепив Bundle перед вызовом метода  - добавил в ответ . За первый вариант еще то , что код будет переиспользуемым , в другой раз у вас может быть больше фрагментов с аргументами и будет уже готовый блок , который нужно только вставить

Comment: Ага, тоже подумал перегрузить, и всего скорее так и сделаю, чтобы как Вы написали "код будет переиспользуемым " :) Большое спасибо! =п.с. интересно, переиспользовать код это профессионально ? крутые андроид девелоперы так делают?)

Comment: только этим и живут . серьезно .

Comment: :)    Хм.. я просто часто юзаю код из своих прошлых проектов..  не думал что так делают тру девелоперы)